# Adding permissions to django users which have add-on models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication

I will be creating an intranet site with multiple roles (client-employee, client-admin, staff team member). Each role will have a model that attaches (via One-to-One or ForeignKey field) to a user with custom fields. I want each role to have it's own set of permissions (like a group).

How can I store this permissions set inside my application. Groups seem to be defined as part of the contrib.admin app rather than in code. I couldn't find anything in documentation on how to define a group.

What is the best way to handle model level permissions. Maybe I could do a check in the model if see if the user has the right role-model.

Answer (score 1):

Access control lists are tricky (some [say dead](http://vimeo.com/2723800)), but Django comes with a good default implementation in `contrib.auth` [equipped with](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#overview):

- Users
- Permissions: Binary (yes/no) flags designating whether a user may perform a certain task.
- Groups: A generic way of applying labels and permissions to more than one user.

A more detailed introduction can be found here:

- http://parand.com/say/index.php/2010/02/19/django-using-the-permission-system/

Comment: Funny, I watched that video yesterday. I guess what I am looking for is that every 'client' user is added to the 'client' group when they are created. That would need to use a signals post_save hook on the user class correct?